# emacsclient -eval "(insert \"something\")" is not working for me

Tags: emacs

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 which comes with Emacs 23. I need Jabref to push citations to Emacs.

However, despite I installed the Jabref plugin to push citations through emacsclient, it's not working.

I did my testing, and read some of the Emacs Lisp Intro.

Some commands do work, for instance if I type (in the console):

```
  emacsclient --eval "(switch-to-buffer \"*sratch*\")"
```

the emacs windows switches to that buffer. However if I issue an insert command:

```
  emacsclient --eval "(insert \"do you see me?\")"
```

no text is inserted in the current buffer.

Does Emacs 23 changed something about insert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo are inserting in *server* buffer, you most likely want:

```
emacsclient --eval '(with-current-buffer "*scratch*" (insert "do you see me?"))'
```

Comment: Thanks! I spent a while reading Emacs Lisp Intro, and while testing the buffer-name function, saw the " *server*" name.

So I think I should reformulate my question into a harder one: Could I insert the text into the "buffer" I'm editing on the current frame? 

Should I write this as separate question and close this one?

Comment: I found it:

(with-current-buffer (window-buffer) (insert "I do see you!"))

Answer (score 3):

Emacs23 change something about emacsclient and server.

The expression is evaluated in the buffer " *server*" (with a leading space)... So you have to change buffer before inserting:

```
  emacsclient --eval "(with-current-buffer \"*scratch*\" (insert \"foo\"))"
```